# Extra vertical space if custom environment ends with displaymath

Tags: spacing, environments, displaystyle

I have defined the following custom `nub` environment in my preamble:

> ```
> \makeatletter
> \newenvironment{nub}[1][\@nil]{%
>     \def\tmp{#1}%
>     \ifx\tmp\@nnil
>         \subsection{}
>     \else
>         \subsection{#1.}
>     \fi}
> \makeatother
> ```

This works perfectly for my needs, except when a nub ends with an `equation`, or any other maths in display mode, because then it adds a bunch more vertical space before the next `nub`.

Here is a screenshot where you can see the extra spacing, before (6.4.4):
[image]

I'm sure there must be some answer for this problem on the site already, but I couldn't find anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting the “end part” in the definition of `nub`, which should be `\ignorespacesafterend`. With the code you show, `\makeatother` is taken instead.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{nub}[1][\@nil]{%
    \def\tmp{#1}%
    \ifx\tmp\@nnil
        \subsection{}
    \else
        \subsection{#1.}
    \fi}{\ignorespacesafterend}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{section}{4}\setcounter{subsection}{2}

\begin{nub}
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
\begin{equation*}
F(x)=G(x)
\end{equation*}
\end{nub}

\begin{nub}[Lemma]
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{nub}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A simpler definition with `xparse`:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{nub}{o}
 {\subsection{\IfValueT{#1}{#1.}}}
 {\ignorespacesafterend}
```

---

#### How I would implement it

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,xparse}

\newtheoremstyle{nub}
  {\topsep}     % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}     % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont} % BODYFONT
  {0pt}         % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries}   % HEADFONT
  {}            % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {(\thmnumber{#2})\thmname{#1}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{nub}
\newtheorem{nubinner}[subsection]{\nubname}
\newcommand{\nubname}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{nub}{o}
 {\IfValueT{#1}{\renewcommand{\nubname}{ #1.}}\begin{nubinner}}
 {\end{nubinner}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{6}\setcounter{section}{4}\setcounter{subsection}{2}

\begin{nub}
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
\begin{equation*}
F(x)=G(x)
\end{equation*}
\end{nub}

\begin{nub}[Lemma]
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{nub}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: just adding the `\ignorespacesafterend` fixed everything, thank you! is there any reason to use your second solution over this fix (besides the code looking much more understandable)?

Comment: @Tim The second solution, the one with `\newtheorem`, is not a hack. Yours is.

Comment: haha, fair enough, thanks!

Comment: for some reason the optional argument (e.g. Lemma) doesn't seem to do anything for me in your second solution...

Comment: @Tim Without seeing your general setup it’s difficult to make a diagnosis

Comment: I was worried that would be the case. unfortunately this is in my thesis, so there's a lot of extra fluff that makes it hard for me to come up with a minimal working example... I'll see what I can try :-)